# Elasticsearch 1.5.0 EsRejectedExecutionException: rejected execution

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm Elasticsearch rookie, have a single-node cluster running Elasticsearch 1.5.0 on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit server.

While doing load-testing experiments, I've noticed that if total number of shards in cluster is greater than thread pools search queue size, all search requests begin to fail with following error:

```
org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsRejectedExecutionException: rejected execution (queue capacity 3000) on org.elasticsearch.search.action.SearchServiceTransportAction$23@4cb7b956
```

The question is: why do I need to keep search queue size greater or equal than total shard number? This looks unreasonable, as I'm forced to have very long search queues. :(((

Maybe my bad? Would be grateful for any useful critics/advice/suggestion.

Thanks!